Set the coordinate axes of the robot arm and D-h parameters and implement them in Matlab
enter image description here
Like the following photo of the robot arm i want to set the coordinate axes arbitrarily and represent the D-H parameters.
And I'm trying to obtain the kinematics and draw the robot line with Matlab code.
